# How can I display information from two related database tables in the one HTML table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, view

I have only just starting using Ruby on Rails and to get used to the language I am working on a small football prediction game. The rules of the game are that from the 10 selected matches each week the user must select what they believe to be the outcome (HOME/AWAY/DRAW) and assign a value from 1-10 for each fixture with each number only allowed to be used once.

A brief overview of my models is as follows:
USERS: username, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at, updated_at
TEAMS: name, created_at, updated_at
FIXTURES: date, home_team, away_team, weekno, result, winner, created_at, updated_at
GAMEWEEKS: number, matches, deadline, created_at, updated_at
SELECTIONS: userid, gameweekno, fixtureno, winner, value, created_at, updated_at

I have the show page set up so that it displays the fixtures from the selected week **i.e week 17 fixtures are accessible through /gameweeks/17** and I am now looking to display the users selections for these fixtures alongside but have encountered some difficulties. My code is as follows for show page:

`<%= notice %>`

```
<h1>Gameweek <%= @gameweek.number %></h1>

<p>
  <b>Number of matches:</b> 
  <%= @gameweek.matches %>
  <b>Deadline Date:</b>
  <%= @gameweek.deadline.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %>
  <b>Deadline Time:</b>
  <%= @gameweek.deadline.strftime("%H:%M") %>
</p>

<table width="100">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Kick Off</th>
    <th>Home</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Away</th>
    <th>Result</th>
    <th>Prediction</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>

<% Fixture.where(:weekno => @gameweek.number).each do |fixture| %> 
  <tr>
    <td width="10"><%= fixture.date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")%></td>
    <td width="10"><%= fixture.date.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
    <td width="80"><%= fixture.home_team %></td> 
    <td width="10">Vs.</td>
    <td width="80"><%= fixture.away_team %></td>
    <td width="10"><%= fixture.result %></td>
    <% Selection.where(:userid => current_user).each do |fixture| %>
    <td width="10"><%= selection.winner %></td>
    <td width="10"><%= selection.value %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_gameweek_path(@gameweek) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', gameweeks_path %>
```

Anyone with tips in how I could correctly call the selection value for the corresponding fixture ensuring that this was the current_user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not necessarily the best way to do this (a lot of logic in the views, but you may want to change the aforementioned part of your code to this:

```
<% Fixture.where(:weekno => @gameweek.number).each do |fixture| %> 
  <tr>
    <td width="10"><%= fixture.date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")%></td>
    <td width="10"><%= fixture.date.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
    <td width="80"><%= fixture.home_team %></td> 
    <td width="10">Vs.</td>
    <td width="80"><%= fixture.away_team %></td>
    <td width="10"><%= fixture.result %></td>
    <% Selection.where(:userid => current_user.id, :fixtureno => fixture.id).each do |selection| %>
      <td width="10"><%= selection.winner %></td>
      <td width="10"><%= selection.value %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I had to correct some of the basic syntax issues. Again, the more advanced you get in rails, the more you will understand where logic should reside, and hopefully learn that this is not the MOST effective way to solve this problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks alot Andrew I will give it a try now.

Just for information purposes what are the basic syntax issues that you mentioned? Also what would you suggest would be a more appropriate model for doing this?

Comment: You didn't have an end tag for you nested form element (Selection), you were only filtering :userid => current_user (instead of current_user.id). You weren't filtering by fixtureno at all. Lastly, you were using |fixture| instead of |selection| in your last .each do block,

Comment: Now, as for logic, you should push these into scopes and set them up in the controller, so you just do @selections.each do |selection| - etc

Comment: Tried the suggestions and I am getting the following errors:

RuntimeError in Gameweeks#show 
Showing C:/Sites/predictor/app/views/gameweeks/show.html.erb where line #34 raised: 

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Comment: Hi Andrew, so silly my bad I was accessing a page without the user being logged in hence this error so thanks for your helped worked a treat :-)

Comment: This is another reason why you would want to handle this logic outside of the view, you can ensure that the user is logged in and/or show different content depending on if they are :) Cheers!

Comment: When you say handle the logic outside of the view what do you mean? I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I am literally one week into learning rails and so am not really up on the best practices